# The setState method is used to update a single state variable at a time. IS this statement True or False. if true why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `setState` method is used to update a single state variable at a time. Is this statement True or False. If true, why?

I'm confusing about that statement. It can also update a single state variable also or only it can update multiples values.

please clarify me about that statement

Comment: Where did you come across this statement? Is this some sort of quiz?

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` can update the entire state of the component. Let's say you have a component:

```js
class App extends Component { 
  constructor(props){ 
    super(props) 
        
    // Set initial state 
    this.state = {
      name: "Nil",
      age: "0",
      score: "0"
    } 
  }
      
  render(){ 
    return ( 
      //... 
    ) 
  } 
}
```

Using the `setState` method you can update 1,2 or all 3 state variables by calling it:

```js
    this.setState({
      name: 'Bob',
      age: '18',
      score: '30'
    })
```

So yes the setState accepts only 1 input argument, but that input argument is the object representing the entire state of the component

Answer (score 0):

It is true, but then your variable could be a list or an object, and contain "inner-variables" if that makes sense.

Also you can call setState multiple time, it's just the way to hook events in modern web clients.